# How is the force balanced in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, free-body-diagram, centripetal-force

[image]In this type of horizontal circular motion (when the string is also horizontal), Which force balances the vertical force of gravity (Mg) ?

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): Is the green particle supported by a horizontal surface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible for a conical pendulum to be horizontal as there is no force countering gravity. Hence the semi-vertical angle willtend to 90 if the string is spun fast enough but the vertical component of the tension will be balancing the the weight of the object

Comment: Hi user353587; we prefer that you don't post the same answer to multiple questions. Flag one of them as a duplicate of the other instead.